# How can I pass variables to a task factory action?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I like to send a mail using a task. This is my code to envoke the SendMail method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail(toTextBox.Text,
                                     subjectTextbox.Text,
                                     BodyEditor.ContentHtml,
                                     filenames.ToArray(),
                                     ccTextBox.Text,
                                     bccTextBox.Text));
```

Problem is: I can't pass UI information (textbox etc..) like this because the objects are owned by another thread.

Error message: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

How should I pass these parameters to my action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you already *in* your UI thread? If so, you merely need to extract the properties first, so that when your lambda expression is called, you've already performed the property access.

For example:

```
string recipient = toTextBox.Text;
string subject = subjectTextBox.Text;
string html = BodyEditor.ContentHtml;
string cc = ccTextBox.Text;
string bcc = bcTextBox.Text();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail(recipient,
                                     subject,
                                     html,
                                     filenames.ToArray(),
                                     cc,
                                     bcc));
```

The variables will be *captured* by the lambda expression - basically the compiler will generate an extra class for you which squirrels away the information, so that when the lambda expression is evaluated, it's still available.

If this code is executing *not* in the UI thread, then you need to basically wrap the whole thing in *another* action, to execute it in the UI thread:

```
Action action = () {
    string recipient = toTextBox.Text;
    string subject = subjectTextBox.Text;
    string html = BodyEditor.ContentHtml;
    string cc = ccTextBox.Text;
    string bcc = bcTextBox.Text();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail(recipient,
                                         subject,
                                         html,
                                         filenames.ToArray(),
                                         cc,
                                         bcc));
};

// Or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action); for WPF/Silverlight.
BeginInvoke(action);
```

Comment: I'm in the UI thread..It works now. Damn it was that easy :)  Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Declare new variables that meats the UI variables values and pass that to the task

```
string to = toTextBox.Text;
string subject = subjectTextBox.Text;
string cc = ccTextBox.Text;
string bcc = bccTextBox.Text;
string files = filenames.ToArray();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail(to, subject,BodyEditor.ContentHtml, files, cc, bcc));
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it work if you didn't use the objects and their properties directly, but instead copied the values that you wish to use into variables and then passed them in instead?